# SharePoint AJAX/jQuery DataTable Stuck Loading

Tags: html, jquery, sharepoint, datatables

I have made huge progress, I couldn't even get the DataTable to append to my landing page on SharePoint, but now the DataTable posts but the Items do not populate. In the code I will provide, it is running to one subsite "XDeliverables" and eventually I am going to need it to pull from three lists. X, Y, & ZDeliverables, but I don't know how to do that within one AJAX call or if it is even possible.

Here is a picture of what my DataTable looks like, it just says Loading...
[image: DataTable Stuck Loading]

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Program</th>
      <th>Deliverable</th>
      <th>To</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Approved</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<script>
  // UMD
  (function(factory) {
    "use strict";

    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
      // AMD
      define(['jquery'], function ($) {
        return factory( $, window, document );
      });
    }
    else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
      // CommonJS
      module.exports = function (root, $) {
        if (!root) {
          root = window;
        }

        if (!$) {
          $ = typeof window !== 'undefined'
            ? require('jquery')
            : require('jquery')( root );
        }

        return factory($, root, root.document);
      };
    } else {
      // Browser
      factory(jQuery, window, document);
    }
  }
  (function($, window, document) {
    $.fn.dataTable.render.moment = function (from, to, locale) {
      // Argument shifting
      if (arguments.length === 1) {
        locale = 'en';
        to = from;
        from = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
      } else if (arguments.length === 2) {
        locale = 'en';
      }

      return function (d, type, row) {
        var m = window.moment(d, from, locale, true);

        // Order and type get a number value from Moment, everything else
          // sees the rendered value
          return m.format(type === 'sort' || type === 'type' ? 'x' : to);
        };
      };
    }));
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    'ajax': {
      'url': "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('XDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
      'headers': { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' },
      'dataSrc': function(data) {
        return data.value.map(function(item) {
          return [
            item.Program,
            item.Deliverable,
            item.To,
            new dueDate(item.Date),
            item.Approved,
            item.Notes
          ];
          console.log(item);
        });
      }
    },
    columnDefs: [{
      targets: 4,
      render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment('YYYY/MM/DD')
    }]
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my error, but now I can't figure out how to call two more URLs with the same type of list? Does anyone know how to do that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    'ajax': {
      'url': "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('XDeliverables')/items?$select=Program, Deliverable, To, Date, Approved, Notes",
      'headers': { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' },
      'dataSrc': function(data) {
        return data.value.map(function(item) {
          return [
            item.Program,
            item.Deliverable,
            item.To,
            item.Date,
            item.Approved,
            item.Notes
          ];
        });
      }
    },
    columnDefs: [{
      targets: 4,
      render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment('YYYY/MM/DD')
    }]
  });
});
</script>
```